# Get Physical Path of KnownFolder

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps

Is there a way to determine the physical path for a known folder in a Windows Store JavaScript app?  My app manifest declares access to the pictures library and I can get the files for that library:

```
Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary.getFilesAsync().then(function (files) {
    // do something with files
});
```

But I'd also like to display to the user the physical path of the `picturesLibrary`.  There is a `path` property on `picturesLibrary`, but it's an empty string.  There's a `folderRelativeId` value as well, which is `"D452C811CB5EB8A4\\Pictures"` so it won't mean much to the user.

I can present the user with a folder picker and allow them to choose the pictures library, then I can get the physical path in the handler for the folder picker.  But is there any way to get the path of a known folder directly in code?

Comment: Why do you want to know the physical path?

Comment: @RossDargan: Just to display it to the user.  The application uses the pictures library by default but allows the user to select a different folder in an options flyout.  I'd just like to re-populate the "current selected folder" with something.  I suppose I could just manually populate it with "Pictures Library", I just thought it would be more consistent to show the actual path since that's what I show after the user selects a different folder.

Comment: ok, well as I said in the comments remember that knownfolder.pictures is actually populated by several folders - so I'm not sure what the correct path to show would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use physical paths like that in your application - the approach you have taken with KnownFolders is the recommended approach.

Trying to navigate a folder programmatically can only be done via either KnownFolders or as you have suggested via a folder picker. The security model will not allow you to do this any other way.

Comment: Are you saying that the security model does not allow the application to know the folder, even though it does allow the application to know the files therein?  I mean, I _could_ just grab the first file and parse out the folder from that.  I'm just looking for a cleaner method.

Comment: Well, that doesn't really make senes since the known folders can be made up of multiple locations (This includes content from a user's local libraries (like Pictures, Documents, Music, or Videos), removable devices, HomeGroup, and media server devices. via http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227151.aspx)

Comment: A single library in known folders (for example, the pictures library) can span multiple physical locations?  Are you sure?  Or are we having some sort of miscommunication here?  I'd be very interested to read more on that if that's the case.

Comment: Further reading seems to indicate this is the case.  I guess I've learned something new.  In any event, that means that what you say makes sense.  There is no one single path (or at least there isn't guaranteed to be) which directly maps to the library.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm positive, go into file explorer, right click on pictures and go to properties - from here you can add folders, and files in these folders will show up in your app.

Comment: No probs, glad it makes sense :-)